# Item Scrolling with Keyboard arrow key in ComboBox WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

In WPF, is there any way to Scroll Up and Down using Keyboard arrow in ComboBox list items?

Comment: You can do this provided that the ComboBox is focused.

Comment: Can you help me on which property to Set from Xaml in ComboBox?

Comment: This is the default behaviour. You shouldn't have to do anything. Try to click on the ComboBox and then use the arrow keys. It should select the items.